# Call a python function from template odoo 8

Tags: templates, controller, web, odoo-8, qweb

There is a function in my controller class, i need to call that function in one of my template. i tried this:

**controller.py**

```
class MyController(http.Controller):
    @http.route(["/myPath/"], type='http', auth="public", website=True)
    def myfucntion(self):
        -- something ---
    def thisMethod(self):
        I need to call this methd in remplate
```

**template.xml**

```
<t t-esc="thisMethod()"/>
```

Getting error:

```
 QWebException: "'NoneType' object is not callable" while evaluating
```

`thiMethod()`

How can call this method?

Comment: you have to provide an instance: `someinstance.thisMethod()`

Comment: how can i create an object for controller class ?

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding you do not actually call the method from the template using t-esc syntax. What you can do is create methods in your controllers which are accessible throught post, or get requests. You can use javascript to make these requests from withing your template if you wish or include the javascript file in your template by a  tag. If the script is simple you could probably get away with inline javascript

```
  <script>console.log("Hello World")</script>
```

Otherwise you can point at a js file within your static directory like this.

```
  <script src="/<module>/static/main.js"></script>
```

Odoo however has some rules for including js. If you are using the Odoo CMS as the parent template for your Qweb template then you may also want to use xpath to place your js file with all the rest of Odoo's js files.

```
  <template id="my_js" inherit_id="website.assets_frontend" name="My Js">
      <xpath expr="script[last()]" position="after">
          <script type="text/javascript" src="/<module>/static/main.js" />
      </xpath>
  </template>
```

In Odoo9 things become (possibly) more complicated as you need to use require js syntax to use post requests within your js.Here is an oversimplified example which should work in Odoo8. For Odoo9 look in the code for other examples using require js.

Here is some controller methods, one json, the other http. Place your code inside whichever works for you. You may choose to return something more appropriate (like some data) but True or False indicating success or failure may be enough.

```
    @http.route('/test/json/method/', auth='none', type='json', website=True)
    def test_json(self):
        #YOUR CODE HERE 
        return json.dumps({'json':True})

    @http.route('/test/http/method/', auth='none', type='http', website=True)
    def test_http(self):
        #YOUR CODE HERE
        return json.dumps({'http':True})
```

Place this javascript using one of the methods (briefly) described above to call the method in your template.

```
        <script>
        jQuery.get('/test/http/method/',function(data){ console.log( "HTTP RESPONSE: " + data ) });
        </script>
        <script>
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/test/json/method/',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        data: JSON.stringify({}),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function ( data ) {
           console.log( "JSON RESPONSE: " + JSON.stringify( data ) );
        },
        failure: function( data ){
           console.log( JSON.stringify( data ) );
        }
    })
    </script>
```

There is a lot to learn when it comes to routing in Odoo. There are security issues, permissions issues which you should be careful of.

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/website.html discusses a quick overview of a few concepts. https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/http.html discusses controllers. https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/javascript.html covers javascript. Other than that take a look in the web, website addons in the controllers directories for more examples.